# How to quantify distribution concentration in cdf?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

For example, let's say I have a list of users, each user has its revenue.

I can plot the cdf of both user and revenue, to see if there is some concentration, for example, may be 40% user contribute 60% revenue, which is not much concentration, like this

[image]

It may also be the case that 1% user contribute to 25% revenue, like this

[image]

My question:

- Is there any formal way, best practice, metrics to quantify such concentration (instead of just showing the charts)

This is especially important as sometimes we're very concern about the top revenue users; if it concentrates heavily, then we might need some alert when this happens.

Comment: Could you please explain more about how the CDFs interact?

Comment: @Dave these cdfs do not interact with each other. every user has its revenue (or you can simply think it as purchase/spending). and then you can plot these 2 cdfs together to see the concentration.

Comment: I mean how you’re using the two graphs together to fit he concentration.

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand the need for the customers cdf. If one wants to look for concentration, it is enough to look for jumps in the  the revenue cdf, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to measure inequality is the [Gini coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) as one of many [metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_inequality_metrics).

However, **depending on your concern and your business problems**, you might want to define a metric on your own.

For example, if the revenue concentration on too few customers causes problems in the **financial balance of the company**, one can estimate a turnover probability (per segment or in total) and then perform a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate the probability that the revenue for next month will be decrease by x %. For example, if the CEO states, that the company has to be 90 % sure that the revenue loss (excluding new customers) will be less 10 %, you have the threshold for an alarm.

On the other hand, if revenue of customers is positively correlated with amount of required consulting, hence creating a **man power issue**, the metric and hence the alarm threshold will be entirely different. If **fear of potential fraud** is the concern, this will also lead to different numbers.

Or as Douglas W. Hubbard in his book *How to measure anything* has put it in the chapter *Clarifying the measurement problem*:

> Prior to making a measurement, we need to answer the following:
>
> - What is the decision this measurement is supposed to support ?
> - What is the definition of the thing being measured in terms of observable consequences and how, exactly, does this thing matter to
>     the decision being asked ?

Based on asking and answering the right questions, your measure of interest can be something as simple as: "If the top 25 % revenue is created by less than 5 customers, raise an alarm".